# Экспорт ArcSegment в DXF.Arc

Tags: c#, wpf

Как экспортировать ArcSegment в DXF.Arc? С # WPF

Comment: А что такое DXF?

Comment: https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/DXF

Comment: Вы пишете просмотрщик DXF? Если вы работаете с `PathGeometry`, там есть `ArcSegment`

Comment: Я понимаю что есть, я не понимаю как ArcSegment который имеет точку начала, точку конца, ширину и высоту перевести в в арку которая имеет 2 углы, центральную точку и радиус.